# Matplotlib requiring latex

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I recently tried to write some simple python code using my school's shared computing resources. I usually use my local computer or SSH in somewhere else. I am running into a seemingly very simple problem which I can't seem to google an answer for. I can't seem to plot anything at all using matplotlib, because matplotlib is looking for latex in order to render (I guess) the axes labels and such (even when I don't explicitly add any text).

A very simple test case:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,3,4,5])
```

gives a very long traceback ending in the error:

```
RuntimeError: Failed to process string with tex because latex could not be found.
```

I have tried pip installing and importing latex but this did not solve the problem.
I would very much appreciate any advice.

Comment: Please show your full code with imports.  Also try `print(plt.rcParams['text.usetex'])`. If that is True, then you are trying to render all your text using LaTeX.  Set it to False: `plt.rcParams['text.usetex'] = False`

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks, I've updated to show the matplotlib import. print(plt.rcParams['text.usetex']) shows False.

Comment: That obviously should not happen.  If you are sure that you are not requesting usetex then please submit a bug to Matplotlib with a reproducible example.